# What does <> signify?

Tags: syntax

I happen to encounter such a structure: `<filename>` which might have an extension name after filename or not. In my file I replace `<filename>` with my desired file name. So according to `\includegraphics{<filename>}`, in my code I write: `\includegraphics{diag1}`. what does <> signify and why it signifies that?
Is it possible to explain various meanings of this combination like a dictionary entry with varried meanings and explanations?

Comment: Usually it denotes something that should be replaced by an instance of the syntactic variable in between; in this case `<filename>` should be replaced by a file name.

Comment: It means you do not have to write *verbatim* ‘filename’, but replace it with the actual name of a file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the `<>` in question simply denotes a placeholder.  This is a general concept not exclusive to TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't agree, I am not a programmer, I'm a literature student with an interest in linguistics. So where should I find an explanation for <>, in C stackexchange? I'm afraid they might say "it is a general concept and not exclusive to C. "

Comment: @nima I think the concept of placeholders for input is very general.

Comment: @HenriMenke We humans define our world with sentences, so the reality is constructed in a narrative and emerges out of  a fiction. As is obvious I had an image of <> in my mind and my question was to seek for a story, a narrative. Some people might find it ridiculous, but my interest in TeX is not solely TeX but paying attention to conventions how people in a programming community talk with each other and how they construct a signifying system, like +_ ∫ in mathematics.

Comment: On the other hand, please let me relate a secret to you. Persian language is full of Arabic words, there is a powerful drive in many Iranian people and "intellectuals" to use archaic persian structures and the period before fusion with arabic. I'm interested in showing that in a very recent phenomena as machine languages the change in syntax and meaning of signs is not an arbitrary process. I guess and expect to find some commands and syntax in TeX which might have a much better alternative but its optimization and removing the barriers would have disastrous effects. Sorry my being talkative.

Comment: @nima Please visit the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) to read my reply.